# _fullpath returns exes current path insted of drive latter

Tags: c++, c, windows

In a windows program I am using _fulpath function to get absolute path of file/directory.

Following is sample code and its output on my box :

```
void PrintFullPath(char * partialPath)
{
    char full[_MAX_PATH];
    if (_fullpath(full, partialPath, _MAX_PATH) != NULL)
        printf("Full path is: %s\n", full);
    else
        printf("Invalid path\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    PrintFullPath("c:\\tmp\\");
    PrintFullPath("c:");
    PrintFullPath("f:");
}
```

> Full path is: c:\tmp\
>
> Full path is: C:\Users\Projects\fullpath\fullpath
>
> Full path is: F:\

In the second PrintFullPath, if I run my exe from some path in C drive,  PrintFullPath gives me program's CWD instead of c:.
First and Third PrintFullPath works fine.

Also if I call PrintFullPath with "c:\\" it works fine.
Any idea why this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's how DOS works.

Open up a command window.  Enter `F:`, for example.  Your current drive will probably change to `F:\`.  Change to another directory on the `F:` drive.  Now, change to `C:` by entering `C:`, and change to a directory on the `C:` drive.  Reenter `F:`, and you'll see you're still in the same directory on the `F:` drive that you were in before.

On Windows, each drive has it's own current directory.  See [Why does each drive have its own current directory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563/)

And `C:` refers to the current directory of the `C:` drive - not the root directory of the `C:` drive as that's represented by `C:\`.